UTF-8 characters are not stored in SQL table in right format
I am trying to write a dataframe in SQL table which is having some extended ASCII characters like 'em-dash', 'pound symbol', but they are not written in the DB table, instead showing some junk characters instead of pound symbol or em-dash.
Is there any alternative way to write down the data in SQL table without corrupting the data. I have used "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=utf8" in my JDBC URL and also used "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;" in my create table schema, but the issue still persists!
JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySchema?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=utf8
Sample Code:
val handleSpecialChar = udf {(make: String) => new String(make.getBytes("UTF-8"))}

val test_df = Seq(
  ("Row 1", "Hello–World"),
  ("Row 2", "Hello—World"),
  ("Row 3", "Hello˜World"),
  ("Row 4", "Hello•World"),
  ("Row 5", "Hello™World"),
)

var test = sparkSession.createDataFrame(test_df).toDF("id", "test_string")
test.show(false)

test = test.withColumn("test_string", handleSpecialChar(test("test_string")))
test.show(false)

test.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("truncate", "true")
  .jdbc(dbUrlMis, "MySchema.testdata", misConnectionProperties)

Create statement of testdata table:
CREATE TABLE mySchema.`testdata` (
  `id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_string` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

Sample database table output after writing: (https://i.sstatic.net/VbnwEOth.jpg)
Sample IntelliJ console output after executing test.show() : (https://i.sstatic.net/zEyRyg5n.jpg)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored
